# How do I redirect the Google Chrome appdata/local folder?

Tags: group-policy, roaming-profile, google-chrome, folder-redirection

The users in our domain use Roaming profiles. Unfortunately Google Chrome saves bookmarks in the Appdata/local folder.

This results in  Chrome "forgetting" the set homepage & bookmarks every time a user relogs.

I downloaded the Chrome ADMX files for group policy but cannot find a way to redirect the appdata/local folder.

Does anyone know of a reliable way to redirect this folder, or atleast secure that Google Chrome does NOT forget the homepage/bookmarks every time a user relogs?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: there are 2 ways to solve this issue you may check [this link](https://downloadgooglechromeall.blogspot.com/2017/01/cannot-read-and-write.html) to solve it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you try `Set user data directory` policy?

It documented [here](http://dev.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#UserDataDir)

And there list of [available path variables](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3/user-data-directory-variables)

In your case it is useful variable `${roaming_app_data}`

Comment: Thanks for your comment Slipeer. Unfortunately I can not find the UserDataDir in the registry. Creating it myself does not help, unfortunately. I was hoping there is a policy to do this using the google Chrome ADMX files.

Comment: I found it! Download the Google ADMX files, go to administrative templates -> Google -> Google Chrome -> Set User Data Directory.